# Finding cycle in singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, cycle

Finding a cycle in singly linked list and find the node from where cycle starts.
I have seen use of two pointers( generally slow and fast) to find the cycle but I have written this code and it seems to be working fine. My question is, is there something my code is missing out on, while finding the cycle in  singly linked list.

```
Node* find_cycle_node(Node *head){
Node *p=head;
     Node *q;
     while(p->next!=null)
    { 
              q=p->next;
        while(q->next!=null)
          { 
                     if(p==q) return q; //Node repeated i.e cycle
                     else (q=q->next;)
           }
                p=p->next;
      }
    return null; // no cycle detected
}
```

Comment: with `return;`, you'll get compiling error. `return NULL`, if no cycle detected

Comment: This site's not for code reviews.  If there's no specific problem with your code that you don't understand, then you should ask for general feedback elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I guess one thing you may want to consider is not only correctness but also runtime. Your algorithm looks like it runs in O(n^2), whereas the two-pointer one (tortoise and hare) runs in something like O(n) time, I believe.

Comment: @J Trana: I also think along the similar lines. But, If I observe it closely, its not exactly O(n^2). For every iteration of outer loop, my inner loop decreases by one node. I am not running inner loop 'n' times in every iteration. Its probably less than O(n^2).

Comment: if O(n) space complexity is accepted, there can be O(n) time complexity algorithm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection describes some common algorithms to solve that.

Answer (score 5):

Your inner loop will not terminate if there is cycle which is a couple nodes down the handle, e.g., it will be an infinite loop for something like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
          ^         |
          |         |
          +---------+
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not get this point. When, pointer p come at node 3, pointer q will be set to node 4 and then node 5 and finally node 3. Now, my condition will be true (p==q) now it will return node q ( i.e. 3 ) and program will terminate.

Comment: @user2773985: in the first outer iteration `p` is at node 1. `q` gets initialized with node 2, moves to node 3 and keeps going through the sequence 4, 5, 3 infinitely. It will never reach a node where the next pointer is null nor will it ever become equal to `p`.

Comment: Oh, there you go! I was not able to find this error. Great Catch.

Answer (score 1):

How about this  ?

```
struct Node_
{
    int ix ;
    struct Node_* next ;
} ;
typedef struct Node_ NODE ;
NODE *head = NULL ;

int main()
{
    NODE* n1 ;
    n1 = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE)) ;
    n1->ix = 0 ;
    n1->next = NULL ;
    head = n1 ;
    NODE* n2 ;
    n2 = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE)) ;
    n2->ix = 1 ;
    n2->next = NULL ;
    n1->next = n2 ;
    NODE* n3 ;
    n3 = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE)) ;
    n3->ix = 2 ;
    n3->next = NULL ;
    n2->next = n3 ;
    NODE* n4 ;
    n4 = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE)) ;
    n4->ix = 3 ;
    n4->next = n2 ;
    n3->next = n4 ;

    unordered_map<NODE*,int> hashx ;
    int idx ;
    NODE* p = head ;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        hashx[p] += 1 ;
        if(hashx[p] >= 2)
        {
            printf("node p (%d) recycle !!\n",p->ix);
            break ;
        }
        p = p->next ;
    }
    printf("done \n") ;
} //main
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there something my code is missing out on

```
return; // no cycle detected
```

This line looks pretty bad, it should be changed to s.th. like

```
return NULL; // no cycle detected
```

Comment: Thanks, edited! I did not notice it since it was not important anyway! but, good find. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To me your inner loop condition appears to be ambiguous. You are analysing if (p==q) where q is p-> next. this means that the node p previously considered didn't haD A CYCLE. So to me your inner loop wil never terminate.

you must consider this:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node * next;
        Node(int x){
            data = x;
            next = NULL;
        }
        Node(int x, Node * y){
            data = x; 
            next = y;
        }
};
class linkedList{
    Node *head;
    public:
        linkedList(){
            head = NULL;
        }
        void addNode(int value){
            Node *p;
            if(head == NULL)
                head = new Node (value, NULL);
            else{
                p = head;
                while(p->next !=NULL)
                    p=p->next;
                    p->next = new Node (value, NULL);
            }
        }
        void print(){
            Node * p;
            p = head;
            while(p != NULL){
                cout << p->data;
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
        int findCycle(){
            Node *p, *start, *q;
            p = head;
            while(p != NULL){
                q = p->next;
                while (q != NULL ){
                    if(p->data == q->data)
                         return q->data;
                    else
                         q = q->next;
                }
                p = p->next;
            }
            return 0;
        }
};
int main(){
    linkedList l1;
    l1.addNode(1);
    l1.addNode(2);
    l1.addNode(3);
    l1.addNode(4);
    l1.addNode(5);
    l1.addNode(3);
    int node = l1.findCycle();
    cout<<node;
    return 0;
}
```

What do you say people about this code.

Comment: Your version also may have infinite loop.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have updated the code. Currently this one is not going in an infinite loop.. . . 

But my question here is that the one who asked a the question is referring to same data at different location as a loop - "Question is from Cracking the Coding Interview." My code is answer to same data . and for it to be a cycle referring to same node we just have to change the if condition to 'if(p == q)' this checks for the memory location. if the memory reference is same then there will be a cycle

Comment: @yashgard1232: OP wants to detect cycle for ill formed list. He doesn't want to find duplicated values. So you misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
void LinkListOps::createCycledListAndFindACycleNode()
```

{
    // build a list with a cycle in it

```
ZNODE* head = new ZNODE(0);
ZNODE* current = head;
ZNODE* cycle = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    current->_next = new ZNODE(i);
    current = current->_next;

    if (i == 6)
        cycle = current;

    if (i == 7)
        current->_next = cycle;
}

// verify that there is a cycle
ZNODE* slow = head;
ZNODE* fast = head;
ZNODE* cycleNode = 0;

while (slow && fast && fast->_next)
{
    slow = slow->_next;
    fast = fast->_next->_next;

    if (slow == fast)
    {
        cycleNode = slow;
        break;
    }

}

if (cycleNode == 0)
{
    printf("No cycle\n");
    return;
}

// finally find a cycle node which will be p2
ZNODE* p1 = head;
ZNODE* p2 = cycleNode;

while (1)
{
    for (p2 = cycleNode; p2->_next != cycleNode; p2 = p2->_next)
    {
        if (p2 == p1)
            break;          
    }

    if (p2 == p1)
        break;

    p1 = p1->_next;
}

printf("%d\n", p2->_i);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly find out if there is a loop in a linked list by doing the following:

```
ptr = head;
current = nullptr;
if (!ptr) {
  current = ptr->next;
  while(current && current!=ptr) {
    current = current->next;
    if (current) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}
```

At the end of this, if `current` is not null, then a loop was found, and `current` will be somewhere inside of it.  This works by iterating `current` twice as fast through the list as `ptr`, and will always find a loop, if any exists, before `ptr` has looped once.